# flash as3 publish for xbox and other game console

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, xbox

Is it possible to publish from as3 air to xbox or any other game consloe?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Hmm. There's [Scaleform](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform), but I'm not sure that's what you're after...

Comment: It's an interesting idea. Do what adobe does for ios, except generate C# xna code instead... I wonder if anyone else has tried doing that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope not as of now. The closest thing available is AIR for TV

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-for-tv.html

http://www.slideshare.net/eladnyc/developing-deploying-air-applications-for-tv